# How to set Retention label to SharePoint Document using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, retention

I am trying to set the retention label (i.e. Office 365 admin under Security & Compliance center) to a file in a SharePoint Online Document Library using CSOM.

I can set the Retention Label using the SetComplianceTag method and it works but it is not setting the policy of retention of the document also it can set any label which we pass in the SetComplianceTag method irrespective that label exist in Office 365 admin under Security & Compliance center section.

Please let me know if is it possible using CSOM?

Please let me know if you need more details of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Go through the below link to add retention policy using CSOM
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-retention-label-and-retention-start-date-to-sharepoint-document-using-csom

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/116826)